# How to access nested json object property inside an array in react-native listview?

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-listview

So, i have a json object like this:

```
[
  {
  "stock": 13,
  "update_stamp": "2017-05-22T20:19:21Z",
  "article": {
    "sku": "0761523",
    "bar_code": "000-111111011",
    "category": null,
    "internal_code": "11"
  }
},
{
  "stock": 3,
  "update_stamp": "2017-05-22T19:38:03Z",
  "article": {
    "sku": "715491",
    "bar_code": "000-111111012",
    "category": null,
    "internal_code": "12"
  }
}
]
```

What logically occurs to me when I'm  trying to access article.sku in a renderRow function is to do something like this:

```
_renderRow(obj: Obj) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.article}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.articleText}>
                {obj.article.sku}
            </Text>
       </View>
    )
}
```

But i get error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'obj.article.sku')
```

When I write something like this:

```
_renderRow(obj: Obj) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.article}>
            <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.articleText}>
                {obj.stock}
            </Text>
       </View>
    )
}
```

It works perfectly fine.

Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Double check if every single item in that array has an article key that's an obj.

Answer (score 0):

So to me, it sounds like obj is what you expect each of your json objects to be. I think you should print out obj to see what it actually is to get a better idea what you are dealing with.

I think, given what you have presented, the obj is not empty. It probably is an object and that's why you are able to access it like so with obj.stock . However, maybe one of your objects' article value is null or maybe the key is just not there. So when you do obj.article, it would return null and you operate sku on that making a null.sku which is an illegal operation.

Comment: Printing of obj.article.sku is fine but problem is passing an obj to renderRow function and trying to access json values there.

Comment: so you have an array of objects and you want to call renderRow on each object correct? So you are probably looping and calling renderRow on each element. What I am saying is to do a console.log within the renderRow function and let us see all of the print outs of each object. like I said, maybe one of the objects have a null article value.